# Match floating number in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a struggle with matching HTML strings with PowerShell. The last two `td` elements have one integer(1) and floating number(11,793). The number `73480` never changes. This numbers(1 and 11,793) can switch their type(integer<=>floating). When i use `[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+` in this case the code is not working. Any idea how to fix it?

```
$web = @"
  <tr bgcolor=#fbf6e9>
    <td align="center">73480    </td>
    <td align="left">Сазлийка    </td>
    <td align="left">Гълъбово    </td>
    <td align="right">1    </td>
    <td align="right">11,793    </td>
  </tr>
"@
[regex]::Match($web,@"
  <tr bgcolor=#fbf6e9>
    <td align="center">73480    </td>
    <td align="left">(\w+)    </td>
    <td align="left">(\w+)    </td>
    <td align="right">([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)    </td>
    <td align="right">([+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)    </td>
  </tr>
"@).Groups[1,2,3,4].Value
```

After I execute the command there is no output(blank result).

Comment: Those who parse HTML with regexes multiply sorrow. Consider using a proper parser, like HTML Agility Pack -- PowerShell supports everything .NET can load.

Comment: I agree with @JeroenMostert but maybe this is what you're looking for? `([+-]?(([0-9]*[.])|([0-9]*))?[0-9]+)`

Comment: There is no output neither with my or your case. Thanks for the sharing HTML Agility Pack way

Comment: Your regex looks like you want to make some sort of data validation, but your code looks like you only want to extract the values (something like `([^<]*)` would have sufficed for that). So what exactly is it you really want to do?

Comment: @marsze I want to get this values from HTML files. This is a part of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text has a decimal comma but your regex tries to match a `[.]`.
I'd also replace all the multiple spaces in the regex with `\s*`
The groups you select don't count the optional sub(group) catching the first fraction.

```
$web = @"
  <tr bgcolor=#fbf6e9>
    <td align="center">73480    </td>
    <td align="left">SampleOne    </td>
    <td align="left">SampleTwo    </td>
    <td align="right">1    </td>
    <td align="right">11,793    </td>
  </tr>
"@

$RE = @"
\s*<tr bgcolor=#fbf6e9>
\s*<td align="center">73480\s*</td>
\s*<td align="left">(\w+)\s*</td>
\s*<td align="left">(\w+)\s*</td>
\s*<td align="right">([+-]?([0-9]*[,\.])?[0-9]+)\s*</td>
\s*<td align="right">([+-]?([0-9]*[,\.])?[0-9]+)\s*</td>
\s*</tr>
"@
[regex]::Match($web,$RE).Groups[1,2,3,5].Value
```

returns here:

```
SampleOne
SampleTwo
1
11,793
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain how you see the right group numbering, please? I don't get it...

Comment: The groups are also counting nested pairs of parentheses in order of the opening one `(`, so Groups[4] is empty as there is no comma following the `1`. As you are only interrested in the whole number - simply ignore that sub group. You might use [named capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) to easier identify the proper ones.

Comment: I see. What about if the 1 changes to 1,2? Because the file change this values every day and this number will be changed tomorrow to floating

Comment: Same as with `11,793`. As the inner group `([0-9]*[,\.])?` is optional due to the `?` the outer group will hold either condition.

Answer (score 1):

Regex parsing is never recommended for HTML.

**If** your HTML is valid XML (yours is not) you can also parse it as such (for simplicity - if you don't want to include any HTML-parsing libraries):

```
# (tested in pwsh v5.1)
([xml]'
  <tr bgcolor="#fbf6e9">
    <td align="center">73480    </td>
    <td align="left">Сазлийка    </td>
    <td align="left">Гълъбово    </td>
    <td align="right">1    </td>
    <td align="right">11,793    </td>
  </tr>
').tr.td | % { $_.'#text'.Trim() }
```

Output:

> 73480
>   Сазлийка
>   Гълъбово
>   1
>   11,793

(Mind that you have to use quotes for the attribute values to make it valid XML.)

Comment: I have multiple tables with similar information. The values that I need are the one near 73480